# How to type unicode characters in php cli

Tags: php

I work with php cli, so on the command line, on a Linux computer. I want to type in a unicode character. How do you do that?

Suppose the character is the euro sign.

In vim I do: ctrl-v shift-u 20ac Enter.

In bash I do: ctlr-shift-u 20ac Enter.

So how in the php cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
echo "\x20\xac";
```

To echo the raw bytes, but what gets displayed will depend on your terminal settings. Things get... [complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/fastest-way-to-get-an-euro-symbol-at-a-prompt).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're talking about the [PHP Interactive Shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php).

Unfortunately the interactive shell has no concept of unicode. You have two options:

- Entering/pasting the characters directly (some European keyboard layouts allow you to enter the Euro sign directly)
- Entering the unicode bytes using escape sequences. For instance `echo "\xE2\x82\xAc";` will get you a Euro sign