# Typing unicode characters into PHP interactive

Tags: php, linux, macos, unicode

This question is similar to [How to type unicode characters in php cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644371/how-to-type-unicode-characters-in-php-cli), but I feel like it didn't answer my question.

I am working on a project with special Unicode characters (specifically U+0250 to U+034F, the IPA Extensions), and like to use PHP interactive mode (`php -a`) to play around with my code. With the bundled PHP on Mac OS X Yosemite with Terminal, I can directly input or paste these characters and use them:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell
php > $special_chars = "spɛʃəl tʃarz";
php > echo "$special_chars" . "ɪz\n";
spɛʃəl tʃarzɪz
php > quit
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

On a CentOS host with a newer version of PHP installed, I just hear the system beep twice quickly for each special char and nothing happens. I can type special chars in the Terminal, but not in PHP interactive. Here's an example trying to paste the same string in CentOS:

```
$ echo "spɛʃəl tʃarz in bash"
spɛʃəl tʃarz in bash
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo "spl tarz"
php > quit
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.4 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2014 16:34:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

I can work around this by not using interactive mode, or by using hex codes, but I'm curious why it works on one host and not the other. Is this some kind of configuration setting I can change in PHP?

Comment: You checked the encoding settings of your cli installation? It might well be that they differ between the two systems, since the way php is installed is completely independent. This also means the preconfiguration might well differ.

Comment: Is your PHP linked against libreadline or libedit? Which version, and what are the locale settings?

Comment: @arkascha I checked php.ini and tried changing different encoding settings without success. Most of the settings appear to default to UTF-8 anyway, which is what I would like. I also  checked the php source rpm (I installed the php56w package from Webtatic at [link](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/), and didn't see any specific settings for encoding in the package SPEC file.

Comment: @mario I see that both the Mac and Linux have libedit linked for php. The Mac is using "libedit.3.dylib" and CentOS is using "libedit.so.0.0.27". I wasn't sure what was meant by locale settings though. Did you mean output of locale? Everything looks to be set to "en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: The CentOS version is definitely too old. You either need to rebuild your PHP runtime, or preload libreadline (might still be ABI compatible) with `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 php560 -a` or something.

Comment: Preloading libreadline resolved this. I might try rebuilding at some point, but this works nicely for now.